# Armbian: dm-raid module has gone missing

Tags: raspberry-pi, kernel-modules, embedded, armbian

I'm running Armbian (stretch) on an OrangePi PC 2. This is how the OS identifies itself on SSH login:

```
Welcome to ARMBIAN 5.58.180813 nightly Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS 4.18.0-rc8-sunxi64
```

I just updated my system (which also updated the kernel), and the `dm-raid` kernel module seems to be missing now. I'm using LVM on the system, and my volume group is inactive and can't be activated:

```
root@picard:~# lvscan 
  inactive          '/dev/vg-data/lv-data' [2.70 TiB] inherit
root@picard:~# lvchange -ay vg-data/lv-data
modprobe: FATAL: Module dm-raid not found in directory /lib/modules/4.18.0-rc8-sunxi64
  /sbin/modprobe failed: 1
  Cannot read target version of RAID kernel module.
  Can't process LV lv-data: raid1 target support missing from kernel?
```

In fact, there is no dm-raid module to be found:

```
root@picard:/lib/modules# find ./* -iname "*raid*"
root@picard:/lib/modules#
```

I tried using `armbian-config` to switch between their `next` and `dev` kernel, to no avail.

Does anybody know how I can get my `dm-raid` back? I would very much prefer not to compile my own kernel on the tiny machine… Thanks!

Comment: This is why I stopped investing on ArmBian. Each new kernel update brings a new kernel problem. You may ask in their forum, they are more familiar with the setup and are pretty friendly and helpful.